# HTTPS url with port number not working on iOS

Tags: ios, node.js, https

I'm sending a simple GET request on an HTTPS url containing a port number. The url looks like this

https://example.com:8080/v1/base

This works perfectly on Android and on any browser..heck even curl. But, I get this error on iOS. If I remove the port number from the above URL, this works perfectly fine!

> Error:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0xa694c50 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.com:8080/v1/base, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.com:8080/api/v1/base, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0xa2410a0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=}

The SSL certificate was issued by DigiCert. The server backend is node v0.10.15 and iOS SDK v6.1

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including any additional parent CA certs beyond your own?

Also, does it work if you use a port other than 8080 or 443? And does it work if you listen on 443 and explicitly attempt to request `https://example.com:443/v1/base`?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var httpsOpt = {
  key  : fs.readFileSync('ssl.plain.key').toString(),
  cert : fs.readFileSync('ssl.crt').toString(),
  ca:[fs.readFileSync('ca.pem').toString(),
      fs.readFileSync('sub.class1.server.ca.pem').toString()],
};
https.createServer(httpsOpt, app)
  .listen('8080', function(){
    console.log('Listening on 8080')
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `requestCert: true` & the CA certificate solved this

```
var https = require('https'),      // module for https
fs =    require('fs');         // required to read certs and keys

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('ssl/ca.crt'),
    requestCert:        true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    if (req.client.authorized) {
        res.writeHead(200, {&quot;Content-Type&quot;: &quot;application/json&quot;});
        res.end('{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;approved&quot;}');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(401, {&quot;Content-Type&quot;: &quot;application/json&quot;});
        res.end('{&quot;status&quot;:&quot;denied&quot;}');
    }
}).listen(443);
```

Comment: I'm curious to know if your issue here has anything to do with my inability to download iOS apps from secure servers. I'm not sophisticated enough with http protocol matters to fully understand what's written here, but I know that I can do Enteprise distribution (from private servers) ONLY if the .ipa file is kept on http, and NOT https. Annoying! Any insight?